# using Ajax to submit an individual form that is within a forEach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have database query that finds all users posts. This query is then used to a create a forEach loop that will create a post for every database result:

```
for($indexPost=0; $indexPost < $postCount; $indexPost++) {

//All information to do with the post

echo<<<_END

<form action="feedLikes.php" id="likePostForm" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="feedIDForLike" class="feedIDForLike" value="$feedID">

<button type="submit" class="likeButton"></button>

</form>

_END;

}
```

I've commented out all the post information as when this loads it is all displaying perfectly. The problem I'm having is when that like button is pressed the following ajax is performed:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $('#likePostForm').on('submit', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    likePost();
 });

});

function likePost()
{  
var feedIDLike = $(".feedIDForLike").val();



     $.ajax({
      url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
      cache: false,
        type: "POST",
         data: {feedIDLike: feedIDLike},
         dataType: "html",
      success: function(html){
          location.reload();
      }
    });
    }
```

This kind of works. When i press the like function, the code within `feedLikesClicked.php` does its job. However, i currently have 5 posts on my feed. When i press like on a post, it gets entered into the database 5 times. This is because the ajax call when like is pressed is being run by every single post rather than the one i clicked on.

My question is, how do i get the ajax to run for this individual form when the form has been created in a loop?

Thanks for any help and i hope it makes sense.

**Things I Tried**

as each form ID has to be unique, i tried changing the form line to:

```
<form action="feedLikes.php" id="likePostForm$feedID" method="post">
```

and then the top line of jquery to:

```
var feedID = $(".feedIDForLike").val();

$('#likePostForm'+ feedID).on('submit', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    likePost();
 });
```

but this unfortunately had the same result

Comment: Your on the right track with what you tried. I would suggest making a data parameter on the form, so do `data-feedID="{$feedID}"` - then you can get the ID using jquery on the form object instead of a seperate element. Your problem is likely that .feedIDForLike contains multiple IDs, as there are likely multiple of these on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I set a data attribute in the form, so each form has it's own set, and since you are using an onsubmit function, you can pass `this` (meaning the selected form) to the `likePost` functiion which you can then easily pull that data-feedID from the passed element. The problem with your code is you were selecting every element that had the class `feedIDForLike`.

```
<?
for($indexPost=0; $indexPost < $postCount; $indexPost++) {

    //All information to do with the post
    echo<<<_END
        <form action="feedLikes.php" id="likePostForm" data-feedID="{$feedID}" method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="likeButton"></button>
        </form>
_END;

}

?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#likePostForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            likePost(this);
        });

    });

    function likePost(elem) {
        var feedIDLike = elem.attr("data-feedID");
        $.ajax({
            url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                feedIDLike: feedIDLike
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your likePost() function inside your submit function and use jquery's this and closest to get the variable.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

 $('#likePostForm').on('submit', function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();

    //try something like this
    var feedIDLike = $(this).closest( ".feedIDForLike" ).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "feedLikesClicked.php",
      cache: false,
        type: "POST",
         data: {feedIDLike: feedIDLike},
         dataType: "html",
      success: function(html){
          location.reload();
      }
    });
 });

});
```